# Python Dictionary : Issue in Mapping Sorted dataframe column to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

Can someone help me understand why python dictionary retain the original data order rather than taking the sorted data.

For Example here is a dataframe (df):

```
    Id       Date
 0  AB001    12-03-2020
 1  AB002    14-08-2023
 2  AB003    16-08-2017
 3  AB001    23-12-2023
```

Upon sorting the "Date" column to newest to oldest:

```
df.sort_values(['Date'],ascending=[False],inplace=True)

     Id       Date
1  AB001 2023-12-23
3  AB002 2023-08-14
0  AB001 2020-03-12
2  AB003 2017-08-16
```

When I map them using the below code

```
date_dict = dict(zip(df['Id'], df['Date']))
```

upon printing the value of Key `ABOO1` --> the output is `2020-03-12` not `2023-12-23`.

why does this happen?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be `2023-08-14`? that date is associated with `AB002`

Comment: a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, so when you save a new key pair value who's key already exists in the dictionary, the old key pair value is overwritten

Comment: Because you have 2 `AB001` keys. The second one is overwriting the first.

Comment: My bad. The Output should be associated to first entry which is the newest date

Comment: If you want the newest to end up in the dictionary, sort them in ascending order.

Comment: @AkshayaB do you want both values to be saved to the dictionary ? or just the newest one ?

Comment: @KaranShishoo only the newest one

Comment: @OysterShucker Looks Simple. will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest date, use [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html):

```
date_dict = df.groupby('Id')['Date'].max().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'AB001': '2023-12-23', 'AB002': '2023-08-14', 'AB003': '2017-08-16'}
```

This is more efficient than sorting to just keep one value, which you could have obtained with an ascending sort (building a dictionary from zip keeps the last occurrence):

```
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
date_dict = dict(zip(df['Id'], df['Date']))
```

Output:

```
{'AB003': '2017-08-16', 'AB001': '2023-12-23', 'AB002': '2023-08-14'}
```

*Note however the different order of the keys.*

---

NB. to convert the date format from your original `DD-MM-YYYY`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```